# Copy table structure with constraint mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How to copy a table structure with all constraints into another table.

I have to copy all tables of existing database to new database using CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl; statement. It is working fine to copy the structure of the table but not able to copy the constraint of that table.

Please check the old table and a new table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `attribute_groups_old` (
 `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `position` int NOT NULL,
 `is_user_defined` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `attribute_family_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `attribute_groups_attribute_family_id_name_unique` (`attribute_family_id`,`name`),
 CONSTRAINT `attribute_groups_attribute_family_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_family_id`) REFERENCES `attribute_families` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=86 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

CREATE TABLE `attribute_groups_new` (
 `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `position` int NOT NULL,
 `is_user_defined` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `attribute_family_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `attribute_groups_attribute_family_id_name_unique` (`attribute_family_id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Anyone please give me a solution of this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: 'CREATE TABLE ... LIKE..does not preserve any.. foreign key definitions' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Is there any other solution to copy structure with constraint in MySQL.

Comment: 'I have to copy all tables of existing database to new database using CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl; statement' -  do you really have to do this or can you backup the tables from existing db and restore to new db?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, I used CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl; statement. Please check the example posted on the issue. I have to copy only structure from the existing database, not with all data.